# What's missing to get my HTTP response to Postman (with C++ boost::asio)

Tags: c++, http-headers, boost-asio, cpprest-sdk, restbed

I'm currently trying to educate myself on the HTTP protocol by experimenting with a minimal HTTP server, made with boost::asio, here's the whole thing:

```
using namespace std;
using namespace boost::asio;
using namespace boost::asio::ip;

//
// TCP Session
//
class TcpSession : public enable_shared_from_this<TcpSession>
{
  uint8_t      mData[8192];
  tcp::socket  mSocket;  
  unsigned int mTcpSessionId;

public:
  TcpSession(tcp::socket && iSocket, unsigned int && iTcpSessionId) :
    mSocket(move(iSocket)),
    mTcpSessionId(iTcpSessionId) {}

  ~TcpSession() {}

  void start() {
    doRead();
  }

private:

  void doRead() {
    shared_ptr<TcpSession> self(shared_from_this());

    mSocket.async_read_some( buffer(mData, 8192),
      [this, self](boost::system::error_code ec, size_t iBytesReceived)
    {
      if (ec.value() == 10058) { // Socket already closed
        return;
      }
      else if (ec) {
        cout << "Session error : " << ec.value() << " " << ec.message() << endl;
        return;
      }

      if (iBytesReceived > 0) {
        cout << string(reinterpret_cast<char*>(mData), iBytesReceived) << endl;
        write(mSocket, buffer("HTTP/1.1 204 No Content\r\n\r\n"));
        mSocket.shutdown(socket_base::shutdown_both);
      }

      doRead(); 
    });
  }

}; // end of TcpSession


//
// TCP Server
//
class TcpServer
{
  tcp::acceptor mAcceptor;
  tcp::socket   mSocket;
  unsigned int  mTcpSessionCount;

public:
  TcpServer(io_service& iService, const short iPort) :
    mAcceptor(iService, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), iPort)),
    mSocket(iService),
    mTcpSessionCount(0) {
    mAcceptor.set_option(tcp::acceptor::reuse_address());
    accept();
  }

private:
  void accept() {
    mAcceptor.async_accept(mSocket, [this](boost::system::error_code ec) {
      if(!ec) {
        make_shared<TcpSession>(move(mSocket), mTcpSessionCount++)->start();
      }
      else {
        cout << "Server error message " << ec.value() << " " << ec.message() << endl;
      }

      accept();
    });
  }
}; // end of TcpServer

int main() {
  io_service ioService;
  TcpServer mTcpServer(ioService, 2112);
  ioService.run();
}
```

When I'm sending a request to this server with Postman, I get the "Could not get any response" message. When I'm trying the same thing with Insomnia, I'm receiving perfectly the expected answer.

Searching on the issue, I understand that Postman would require me to use the system proxy to get the message. I already had some fun with RestBed and CPPREST, but I never had that king of issue before. I get that CPPREST and RestBed must be doing something more to manage/wrap the response, but what?

What are CPPREST and RestBed doing that I'm not? Do I need a specific header to make my server responses more generally acceptable? Or maybe I should setup my acceptor/socket differently?

Comment: I do not understand why you need to use any kind of proxy for localhost tcp

Comment: Honestly me neither, but I figure I can/should probably do a little more if  a software like Postman doesn&#39;t pick it up.